# Flutter: 'Future.wait' multiple async functions in parallel VS 'await' one at a time. <= different results

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await

I recently learned of the fabulous way of waiting for multiple async functions to complete using `Future.wait([asyncFuncOne(), asyncFunctwo()])`

However, I noticed two different outcomes when running either of these blocks of code. One awaiting each function to finish, the other using `Future.wait` for parallel processing. What am I doing wrong?

Method 1:

```dart
    await msm.initProfileData();
    await msm.initActivityFeed();
    await msm.getRecentlyActiveUsers();
    await msm.getRecommendedUsers();
    await msm.getGroups();
    await msm.getFollowing();
    await msm.getFollowers();
```

Method 2:

```dart
    await Future.wait([
      msm.getFollowing(),
      msm.initProfileData(),
      msm.initActivityFeed(),
      msm.getRecentlyActiveUsers(),
      msm.getRecommendedUsers(),
      msm.getGroups(),
      msm.getFollowers(),
    ]);
```

in Method 1, all the async functions complete before my apps home screen appears. In Method 2 the home screen appears before all the async functions complete.

Cheers and thanks in advance.

EDIT: Additional code example.

```dart
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    googleSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged.listen((account) {
      handleSignIn(account);
    }, onError: (err) {
      print('Error signing in: $err');
    });
    googleSignIn.signInSilently(suppressErrors: false).then((account) {
      handleSignIn(account);
    }).catchError((err) {
      setState(() => _showSignIn = true);
      print('Error signing in: $err');
    });
  }

  handleSignIn(GoogleSignInAccount account) async {
    if (account != null) {
      await createUserInFirestore();
      setState(() {
        isAuth = true;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        isAuth = false;
        _showSignIn = true;
      });
    }
  }

  createUserInFirestore() async {
    final GoogleSignInAccount user = googleSignIn.currentUser;
    DocumentSnapshot doc = await usersRef.document(user.id).get();
    //...
    //do stuff
    //...
    await someFunc1(); //Method1
    // await comeFunc2(); //Method2
    //do more stuff
  }

  someFunc1() async {
      msm.asyncfunc1();
      msm.asyncfunc2();
  }

  someFunc2() async {
      await Future.wait([
          msm.asyncFunc1(),
          msm.asyncFunc2(),
      ]);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return isAuth ? buildAuthScreen() : buildUnAuthScreen();
  }
```

Comment: As you thought, there is no reason that the behaviour of the Future.wait differs.
Maybe your problem is elsewhere ? Can you give more code ?

Comment: Note that method 1 forces each asynchronous operation to complete in sequence; the next asynchronous operation won't be started until the previous operation completes. Method 2 makes no such constraints; the asynchronous operations may complete in any order.

Comment: I've tried leading the 'handleSignIn()' with await, but it didn't make a difference to my surprise. The extra odd thing is that Method one holds up the loading screen significantly longer, regardless of the await in from of 'handleSignIn()' :(
I've struggled to find good resources on intermediate/advanced flutter knowledge. Please do share if you have a good resource to explore :D

Comment: @jamesdlin but method 2 will still wait for all functions to complete, correct?

Comment: just realized the setState in handleSignIn is redundant since called from init state...
I will try without setState calls.

Comment: Yes, both methods will wait for all functions to complete. As long as none of those functions are dependent on any of the others, method 2 should work in principle.

Answer (score 3):

Using `Future.wait(List<Future>)` will wait for all the async operations without sequence as mentioned in the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future/wait.html). While using await consecutively, it'll wait for the first await async operation to finish before running the next await async operation. If you have a prerequisite output before running the next async operation, it's better to use await async in sequence instead.